# How to draw vertical shape in the centre of XML drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How can a vertical line be drawn within an XML drawable when using a `layer-list`? I declared 3 shapes within the drawable but for some reason it doesn't appear as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Current result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:width="16dp"
    android:left="15px">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />/>
        <size android:width="5dip" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="16dp"
    android:left="80px">

    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />/>
        <size android:width="5dip" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:width="16dp"
    android:left="140px">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />/>
        <size android:width="5dip" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Im  not sure :/ ...Anyway, you can use the other example. Add the shape in a separate layout file and use <include layout="" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

drawable/shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />/>
<size android:width="5dip" />
<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"
    />
</shape>
```

Include in the layout file the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<View
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"></View>

<View
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"></View>

<View
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"></View>

</LinearLayout>
```

Change the colors and fix the margins of the layout.

Comment: You can try a layer-list ... check out my next comment